# git push over smart HTTP fails with 403

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, http, git

This has been driving me nuts. I'm running git 1.7.8.rc4 with Apache/2.2.14 on Lucid Ubuntu, and set up LDAP authentication.  The authentication seems to be working fine, and i can pull, but i can't push without getting a 403 error.

```
[Fri Dec 16 20:04:25 2011] [error] [client 10.60.226.130] client denied by server configuration: /opt/tools/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
```

My apache site file:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /opt/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER

ScriptAlias /git/ /opt/tools/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Directory "/opt/git">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/opt/tools">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        AuthName "GIT Repo"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.59.10.40:389/dc=shopping,dc=com"
        Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Everything i find regarding "client denied by server configuration" says "Add 'Order allow,deny / Allow from all' to the correct Directory entry."  It's there, and it's still not working.  Any ideas?  I know i'm really close and is probably something super simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue was in the LocationMatch block:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

was causing the 403 error. Change it to be permissive as in the Directory block and it changes to a 401, which turned out to be a problem with the LDAP authentication. I changed the AuthBasicProvider to 'external' and used pwauth as per ([pyxzl.net/store/authnz.php](http://pyxzl.net/store/authnz.php))